# Configuration of Running Redis Instance in Swisscom CloudFoundry

Tags: redis, swisscomdev

I am trying to read the configuration of the running Redis instance. I want to better understand how Redis is configured, especially in regard to persistence settings.

I have successfully connected to the running Redis instance (SSH tunnel) and try to execute the following command:

```
CONFIG GET *
CONFIG GET appendonly
```

However, I get the message

```
ERR unknown command 'CONFIG'
```

If I invoke the command "CONFIG GET" without any parameters I get the message

```
Invalid input argument for command: 'CONFIG GET', passed 0 arguments, must be in range 1 - 1
```

So the command is known. Seems to be a permission issue!? Is there a way to get the configuration?

Comment: For security reasons the `CONFIG` command is not available. What are the parameters your are interested in?

Comment: appendfsync and appendonly. The question boils down to what persistence guarantees the Redis instances provide. E.g. is it just suitable for caching or can we use it as general purpose key value store.

Answer (score 0):

The current Redis offering (march 2019) has the following settings for persistency:

```
appendonly yes
appendfsync everysec
```

It runs with 2 replicas.

Please note that this allies to the current service offering of Swisscom and might change in the future.

Comment: Weakening the persistence guarantees would be a very bad idea as applications will rely on the guarantees you provide today.

Comment: It's just a general statement. I'm not aware that the persistence should be changed. For sure this would be announced.